# Numpy- how to sample a line in world coordinates to pixel coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, bresenham

I have a line given as

`x1,x2`, `y1,y2`.

In WORLD coordinates.

Assuming we place the image plane, whose center (or corner) is at `xc,yc`, and whose resolution is `w,h` pixels.

I would like to get an efficient way of getting **the list of pixels of the given line, sampled at the picture's pixels it intersects**

I am aware of the [bresenham algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm&ved=2ahUKEwibl-Dm873fAhWvShUIHcDjA2EQmhMwDHoECAsQPQ&usg=AOvVaw1Z6HAPBIKoibJWjSJ4TeFn), but a pythonic implementation is slow.

Is there a numpy way of doing this?
Is there another python library for doing this?
Is there a way to do this for many lines, all in some vectorized way?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the line's thickness and whether it was drawn with anti-aliasing?

Comment: I would take any answer that utilizes numpy, and augment from there

Comment: Have you tried drawing the lines, say in white on a black background, with an efficient, optimised library and then finding the non-zero pixels with Numpy?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 1. Like what library for example? 2. Does this make sense? It would increase complexity to O(h*w) instead only O(line_pixels)

Comment: Like OpenCV `line()` for example https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html